# Pandas - Create a new column with aggregation of previous column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 2 columns:

```
CLASS   STUDENT
'Sci'   'Francy'
'math'  'Alex'
'math'  'Arthur'
'math'  'Katy'
'eng'   'Jack'
'eng'   'Paul'
'eng'   'Francy'
```

I want to add a new column with all the students in the class 'math'

```
CLASS   STUDENT  NEW_COL
'Sci'   'Francy'   NaN
'math'  'Alex'    'Alex', 'Arthur, Katy'
'math'  'Arthur'  'Alex', 'Arthur, Katy'
'math'  'Katy'    'Alex', 'Arthur, Katy'
'eng'   'Jack'     NaN
'eng'   'Paul'     NaN
'eng'   'Francy'   NaN
```

I have been trying something like this but I am not getting very far :

```
def get_all_students(class_series, df):
    return df.groupby(['CLASS','STUDENT']).size().rest_index()['CLASS'== measurement].tolist()
    ...

df['NEW_COL'] = np.where(df['CLASS']=='math', get_all_students(df['CLASS'],df),np.NaN)
```

Comment: Why Jack in Math class but not Alex?

Comment: @QuangHoang Sorry, typo. It's correct now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC Using condition assign with the `groupby` + `transform`

```
df.loc[df.CLASS=='math','New']=df.groupby('CLASS').STUDENT.transform(','.join)
df
Out[290]: 
  CLASS STUDENT               New
0   Sci  Francy               NaN
1  math    Alex  Alex,Arthur,Katy
2  math  Arthur  Alex,Arthur,Katy
3  math    Katy  Alex,Arthur,Katy
4   eng    Jack               NaN
5   eng    Paul               NaN
6   eng  Francy               NaN
```

More info, since I compute all the group by `groupby` , so that you can assign them all or just pick what you need conditional assign

```
df.groupby('CLASS').STUDENT.transform(','.join)
Out[291]: 
0              Francy
1    Alex,Arthur,Katy
2    Alex,Arthur,Katy
3    Alex,Arthur,Katy
4    Jack,Paul,Francy
5    Jack,Paul,Francy
6    Jack,Paul,Francy
Name: STUDENT, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `str.join`:

```
df.loc[df['CLASS'] == 'math', 'new_col'] = ', '.join(df.loc[df['CLASS'] == 'math', 'STUDENT'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"CLASS":['sci','math','math','math','eng','eng','eng'],"STUDENT":['Francy','Alex','Arthur','Katy','Jack','Pauk','Francy']})
```

step 1: define your function

```
def get_student_list(class_name): 
    students = list(df[df['CLASS']==class_name]['STUDENT'])
    return ", ".join(students)
```

Step 2: use the numpy where func:

```
requested_class = 'math'
df['NEW_COL']=np.where(df['CLASS']==requested_class,get_student_list(requested_class),np.NaN)
```

Desired result:

[image]

Comment: What if 'Katy' was now 'Arthur' (i.e. names are not unique anymore), and we now need 'Alex, Arthur' in new_col instead of 'Alex, Arthur, Katy'?

Comment: @Kaisar Oh I see what you mean, in this case - use set (instead of list) in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `pivot_table` and `map`:

```
df['NEW_COL'] = df.CLASS.map(pd.pivot_table(df, 'STUDENT', 'CLASS', 'CLASS', aggfunc=','.join)['math']).fillna(np.nan)

Out[331]:
  CLASS STUDENT           NEW_COL
0   Sci  Francy               NaN
1  math    Alex  Alex,Arthur,Katy
2  math  Arthur  Alex,Arthur,Katy
3  math    Katy  Alex,Arthur,Katy
4   eng    Jack               NaN
5   eng    Paul               NaN
6   eng  Francy               NaN
```