# Create column with aggregation of previous column - based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

Dataframe with 3 columns:

```
FLAG CLASS   STUDENT
yes 'Sci'   'Francy'
no  'Sci'   'Alex'
yes 'math'  'Arthur'
yes 'math'   NaN
yes 'eng'   'Jack'
yes 'math'  'Paul'
yes 'eng'   'Zach'
```

I want to add a new column ALL_STUD with all the students in each class. But, do this only for the rows with FLAG = yes. Result below:

```
FLAG CLASS   STUDENT   ALL_STUD
yes 'Sci'   'Francy'  'Francy, Alex'
no  'Sci'   'Alex'     NaN
yes 'math'  'Arthur'  'Arthur, Paul'
yes 'math'   NaN      'Arthur, Paul'
yes 'eng'   'Jack'    'Jack, Zach'
yes 'math'  'Paul'    'Arthur, Paul'
yes 'eng'   'Zach'    'Jack, Zach'
```

I have been trying something like this:

```
df.loc[df['FLAG']=='yes', 'ALL_STU'] = df.groupby('CLASS').STUDENT.transform(','.join)
```

But the students from the class 'math' cannot be transformed with `(','.join)` into   `'Arthur, Paul'` because there's an empty name `NaN`in the math class. Any solution, or other way to do this?

Continuation from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050571/pandas-create-a-new-column-with-aggregation-of-previous-column/56050828?noredirect=1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
f = lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna())
#alternative 
#f = lambda x: ','.join(y for y in x if y == y)
df.loc[df['FLAG']=='yes', 'ALL_STU'] = df.groupby('CLASS').STUDENT.transform(f)
print (df)
  FLAG   CLASS   STUDENT          ALL_STU
0  yes   'Sci'  'Francy'  'Francy','Alex'
1   no   'Sci'    'Alex'              NaN
2  yes  'math'  'Arthur'  'Arthur','Paul'
3  yes  'math'       NaN  'Arthur','Paul'
4  yes   'eng'    'Jack'    'Jack','Zach'
5  yes  'math'    'Paul'  'Arthur','Paul'
6  yes   'eng'    'Zach'    'Jack','Zach'
```

You can also filter in both sides for avoid to append values not match condition:

```
mask = df['FLAG']=='yes'
f = lambda x: ','.join(x.dropna())
df.loc[mask, 'ALL_STU'] = df.loc[mask, 'STUDENT'].groupby(df['CLASS']).transform(f)
print (df)
  FLAG   CLASS   STUDENT          ALL_STU
0  yes   'Sci'  'Francy'         'Francy'
1   no   'Sci'    'Alex'              NaN
2  yes  'math'  'Arthur'  'Arthur','Paul'
3  yes  'math'       NaN  'Arthur','Paul'
4  yes   'eng'    'Jack'    'Jack','Zach'
5  yes  'math'    'Paul'  'Arthur','Paul'
6  yes   'eng'    'Zach'    'Jack','Zach'
```

Comment: If we filter in the right side too, the result for the first element in ALL_STUD column would be only 'Francy' and not 'Francy, Alex' . This is because Alex has been filtered out by the mask (right side mas) before doing the grouping_by. Is this thought correct?

Comment: @Kaisar - Yes, exactly.